# How are Bayesian models implemented in the NEF?

Tags: theoretical-neuroscience, nef, bayesian

One of the much documented problems of Bayesian approaches to cognitive modeling is that there isn't much of a [neural grounding](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/600/4397). The NEF can be used to compute probabilistic computations with ease (see Chapter 9 of [Neural Engineering](http://compneuro.uwaterloo.ca/publications/eliasmith2003a.html)), however have this been used in a published model before? Are there drawbacks that make merging the NEF with Bayesian modelling methods unfeasible in terms of resources required?

Comment: The thesis, [Neural Plausibility of Bayesian Inference](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Neural-Plausibility-of-Bayesian-Inference-Sharma/985de6659475aeb15846f017239c7f93d8f729ee), has been available for a few years. Haven't managed to write an answer about it yet :(